# Combinatorics in Python - Fermi -Dirac Statistics

Tags: python, combinatorics

Fermi Dirac statistics implies that the number of microstates within a macrostate for distinguishable particles follows an equation of the form:

Combinations = m!/((m-N)!N!

Pretending m is the number of bouncy balls in a container, and N is the number of bouncy balls you're taking out, this tells us how many unique ways you can take out N balls for N < m.

I'm trying to write a code in python to read out each combination, and need some help. So far all I have is the script telling me how many combinations there are. If m = 4 and N = 2, there are 6 combinations. I need to write a code that tells me that those combinations are the first and second, first and third, first and forth, second and third, second and forth, and third and forth. Now for small m this is easy to do by hand but you can see this gets monotonous fast. Can someone help me write a script to do this?

```html
import math
print 'Enter a Value for m'
m = int(raw_input());
print 'Enter a Value for N'
N = int(raw_input());

print math.factorial(m)/(math.factorial(m-N)*math.factorial(N))
```

Comment: ps. if you downvote, it be really helpful to know why so that I don't ask poorly worded questions!

Comment: I'd just write some little recursive algorithm if you don't need to really optimize performance

Comment: Or use itertools combinations()

Comment: You changed the question completely. If you have a different question, create a new question.

Comment: My friend thought it would be hilarious to change my question completely. I'm sorry about that everyone

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial using itertools.combinations

```
import itertools

M=4
N=2

for combo in itertools.combinations(range(M),N):
    print combo
```

Output:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

Itertools docs for Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
Itertools docs for Python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sketch of an algorithm that should handle this.

```
def combinations(currentPosition, maxPosition, numToInclude):
    if numToInclude = 0 or currentPosition > maxPosition:
        return [[]]
    finalList = []
    listOfCombinations = combinations(currentPosition+1,maxPosition,numToInclude-1)
    for i in range(len(listOfCombinations)):
        finalList[2*i] = [1] + listOfCombinations[i]
        finalList[2*i+1] = [0] + listOfCombinations[i]
    return finalList
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Use itertools.combinations. It is in the standard library. There is even pseudocode for it.

Comment: Can you explain this algorithm a little bit? I'm having a hard time incorporating my problem into it.

Comment: That's why you should use itertools.combinations. No coding required by you, therefore no possibility of errors being introduced by you, or by its author (no disrespect intended, Erik).

Comment: You all have been very helpful. Thanks so much

Comment: No disrespect received barny. If I always wrote perfect code, I'd be making a lot more money then I am.